# Check server logs through terminal

Tags: php, logging, amazon-web-services, terminal

I use AWS. I want to check server logs through terminal on mac. I have ssh key and logged in to server through terminal. I want to run server code and see its logs.

How to do it?

Comment: you can use tools such as `grep`, `tail`, `cat`

Comment: @DevZer0 But I don't know where will I  find logs. there should be some file with particular name.

Comment: use `find / -name [filename|portion\*]`

Comment: @DevZer0 My doubt is that I don't know anything that what is the file name and where it is placed or anything.

Comment: use `lsof` to find out the list of open files when a process is running, and `grep` for the specific process name to find the open files

Comment: @DevZer0 Ok. But is there any specific name for log file? There are lots of open files.

Comment: @DevZer0 Using `grep` command prints few file names, but it says "permission denied". Thus I can't get assured that this is the file I am looking for. Is there any work around to this permission denied error?

Comment: Logs files are mostly stored under /var/log/*

Comment: @Stewie Yes, it was under /var/log. I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found log files under `/var/log` directory. There were so many log files in this directory. I needed to use `sudo`, otherwise I get permission denied.